# Which version of python do I need for using numpy.linalg.slogdet?

Tags: python, numpy, condor

I'm running my python script on Condor using the requirement `Requirements = (HAS_NUMPY =?= TRUE)`. 
This works for normal numpy functions, but when I use `numpy.linalg.slogdet` function I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/condor/execute/dir_17583/condor_exec.exe", line 11, in <module>
    ans=np.linalg.slogdet(a)[1]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'slogdet'
```

Although its hard for me to know which version of python exists on that node, the version on the main condor machine is 2.6.6.

The code is very simple:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.diag(np.arange(1,9))

ans=np.linalg.slogdet(a)[1]
```

My question is:
Is this error occuring because np.linalg.slogdet needs a higher version of python?
If so, is there a way to specify the python version required on Condor?

Update:

Used mgilson's suggestion and found that the numpy version is 1.4.1, hence the problem.
So, now this is a Condor question :  is there a way to specify the version of numpy required in the Condor submit file; something better than `Requirements = (HAS_NUMPY =?= TRUE)` ?
Thanks

Comment: It appears that [numpy.linalg.slogdet](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.slogdet.html) was introduced in numpy 1.6.  To check your numpy version, you can print `numpy.__version__`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better check the `numpy` version on your machine:

```
In [50]: np.version.version
Out[50]: '1.8.1'
```

since the docs says, `np.linalg.slogdet` function is *"versionadded:: 1.6.0."*

Comment: Thanks, used it and found the version was 1.4.1. That was the problem.